# Conditional aggregates for every row of a data frame and append it as a new column value

Tags: r, dplyr, mapply

I have tried to write some code to do conditional aggregates for every row of a data frame and append it as a new column value. The example is calculating season average statistics for every team in the nab game at a point in the NBA season.

This code I can get to run and it does what I want:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(game_data)) {
  # do something with df[i, "col1"], df[i, "col2"], and df[i, "col3"]
  wins <- game_data %>% filter(season == game_data[i, "season"]) %>% filter(game_date < game_data[i, "game_date"]) %>% filter(team_id == game_data[i, "team_id"]) %>% group_by(team_id) %>% summarize(x=sum(wl == "W"))
  if(nrow(wins) != 0)
  {
    game_data[i, "w_tot"] <- wins[2]
  }
}
```

Where game_data is a data frame. This is the code I thought would be used but I can seem to get it to run:

```
wins_up_to_function <- function(curr_season, curr_date, curr_teamId)
{
  game_data %>% filter(season == curr_season) %>% filter(game_date < curr_date) %>% filter(team_id == curr_teamId) %>% group_by(team_id) %>% summarize(x=sum(wl == "W"))
}

mapply(X = game_data, MARGIN = 1, FUN = wins_up_to_function, curr_season = df[,'season'], curr_date = df[,'game_date'], curr_teamId = df[,"team_id"])
```

Can you kind folks help understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can suggest some sample data (as code we can run), and also describe what you expect to happen. As is, we have to imagine some data and then imagine what your code is supposed to be doing to it and compare that to what we imagine your code is actually doing to it.

Comment: Guessing, maybe `game_data %>% group_by(team_id, season) %>% mutate(w_tot = cumsum(wl == "W"))`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this works:

```
wins_test <- game_data %>%
  group_by(season, team_id) %>%
  arrange(game_date) %>%
  mutate(w_tot = cumsum(wl == "W")) %>%
  ungroup()

game_data_test <- game_data %>%
  left_join(wins_test %>% select(season, team_id, game_date, w_tot), by = c("season", "team_id", "game_date"))
```